# Implementing Grizzly Websockets with Glassfish 3.1.2 and Spring

Tags: java, spring, websocket, glassfish-3, grizzly

I'm trying to add web-socket notifications to an old application running on Glassfish 3.1.2 and Spring 4.1.5-RELEASE. Implementing Spring's websockets is not working because it needs GlassFish 4.1+ and we cannot upgrade the application server. I'm using Grizzly web-sockets 1.9.x and I created a very basic `@Component` extending the `WebSocketApplication` class and implementing bean-events-related interfaces.
Here is the object

```
@Component
public class CCMarshaller extends WebSocketApplication implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean   {

    private static final String TOPIC = "/realtime-channel";

    @Override
    public WebSocket createWebSocket(ProtocolHandler protocolHandler, WebSocketListener... listeners) {
        return new DefaultWebSocket(protocolHandler, listeners);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isApplicationRequest(Request request) {
        final String uri = request.requestURI().toString();
        return uri.endsWith(TOPIC);
    }

    /* Test */
    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket socket, String text) {
        EventDto e = new EventDto();
        e.setId(45);
        broadcast(e);
    }

    private void broadcast(EventDto evt) {
        for (WebSocket webSocket : getWebSockets()) {
            if (!webSocket.isConnected()) {
               continue;
            }
            try {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                webSocket.send(mapper.writeValueAsString(evt));
            } catch (WebSocketException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                webSocket.close();
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                webSocket.close();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        WebSocketEngine.getEngine().register(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        WebSocketEngine.getEngine().unregister(this);
    }

}
```

I'm pretty new to Spring world, but my understanding of lifecycle of this bean is (approx): (1) singleton creation at startup, (2) then the framework calls afterPropertiesSet, (3) which registers the WebSocketApplication object (this) and (4) every request to /realtime-channel will be handled by WebSocketApplication calling the `OnMessage` callback. The `broadcast` function is an helper for broadcasting an object to all connected sockets (object is converted to json).

It works... for a while :)

When the application starts I can login and navigate the first page where the javascript connection is done with few lines of code:

```
var WSManager = {
        url: 'ws://' + window.location.host + '/realtime-channel',
        init: function() {
            websocket = new WebSocket(WSManager.url);
            websocket.onmessage = function (evt) {
                // process message with jquery
            };
        }
    };
WSManager.init();
```

after the client is connected via websocket, the application can send messages and  receives (in broadcast) object, so it's working good. Even if i connect with other websocket test tools ot's working good. 
The problem arises when I try to navigate to other pages (pure Spring navigation). The application hangs and server.log shows the following messages:

```
[#|2017-11-24T13:36:32.350+0100|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=139;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|StandardWrapperValve[mvc-dispatcher]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:570)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncUtils.getAsyncManager(WebAsyncUtils.java:49)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1023)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.execute(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:159)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:145)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:210)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
|#]

[#|2017-11-24T13:36:32.351+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter|_ThreadID=139;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC3989: An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.setAttribute(Request.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.setAttribute(RequestFacade.java:570)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.exception(StandardWrapperValve.java:465)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.execute(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:159)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncExecutor.interrupt(DefaultAsyncExecutor.java:145)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:210)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
|#]

[#|2017-11-24T13:36:32.354+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=139;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.obtainAndSetThreadAttachment(AsyncProcessorTask.java:230)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.enableTimeout(AsyncProcessorTask.java:223)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:127)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:210)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
|#]

[#|2017-11-24T13:36:32.354+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=139;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Processor exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:140)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:210)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.obtainAndSetThreadAttachment(AsyncProcessorTask.java:230)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.enableTimeout(AsyncProcessorTask.java:223)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:127)
    ... 14 more
|#]
```

I already launched this command on glassfish:

```
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.websockets-support-enabled=true
```

It seems that somewhere Spring is loosing the REQUEST object, that seems to be null. Maybe there is some sort of configuration I have to do in web.xml file related to the URL /realtime-channel?

If I remove the websocket registration `WebSocketEngine.getEngine().register(this);` everything works fine, but the websocket, of course, does not work anymore.

### OTHER EXCEPTIONS

Sometimes the application throws other exceptions as well:

```
[#|2017-11-24T14:47:11.655+0100|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=123;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.obtainAndSetThreadAttachment(AsyncProcessorTask.java:230)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.enableTimeout(AsyncProcessorTask.java:223)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:127)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:210)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
|#]

[#|2017-11-24T14:47:11.657+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=123;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Processor exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:140)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:193)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.TaskBase.execute(TaskBase.java:175)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.DefaultAsyncHandler.handle(DefaultAsyncHandler.java:145)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProtocolFilter.execute(AsyncProtocolFilter.java:210)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.obtainAndSetThreadAttachment(AsyncProcessorTask.java:230)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.enableTimeout(AsyncProcessorTask.java:223)
    at com.sun.grizzly.arp.AsyncProcessorTask.doTask(AsyncProcessorTask.java:127)
    ... 14 more
|#]
```

### UPDATE

If I define a `HandlerInterceptor` for all the URLs and add breakpoints I can see that the exceptions are raising **after** the execution of `preHandle` hook and after the execution of `postHandle` hook (in both functions the `HttpServletRequest` object is valid).

Answer (score 0):

After some days I managed to solve this issue upgrading to Glassfish Server 3.1.2.2 with Grizzly Framework 1.9.50, because Grizzly Framework 1.9.46 does not seem to work with web sockets.